# MySQL DATE_ADD INTERVAL 1 SECOND not working

Tags: mysql, dateadd

I'm facing currently very, very strange behaviour.

I have an enterprise application, running on JBoss, the ORM is as you might expect hibernate and I'm doing some bulk operations.
I have a table and in that table there are all kind of fields and among the others there is a field of type DATETIME. In this field I'm saving user info, I have another field of the same type, configured with an trigger, so every time when the row is being updated the second DATETIME field is also updated.
I have a case where the first field should be increased with one second, so I'm doing bulk copy something like this:

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET customerDATE = DATE_ADD(customerDATE, INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

My problem is that the query does not always work as expected.
What I see is that the second DATETIME field(the onne with the trigger) is being updated, together with some other fields, but the auto-increment with one second does not alway works(sometimes is also increased, sometimes not).

I tried searching for some known issues, but without success.
If anybody knows some problem in this direction I would really appreciate any help!

I'm testing now if there will be problems with more than an extra second.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a comma might be missing with the DATE_ADD?  `DATE_ADD(customerDATE, INTERVAL 1 SECOND)` ... based on information here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Comment: yeah, you are right but the code was just a dummy :) there are no syntax errors in the real case

Comment: To the "auto-increment with one second"... is that column a unique or primary key? ... possibly causing a conflict, so that there is no update on that column?

Comment: nope, there are no constraints or something. The funny thing is that it's working for single rows, and for the most of the rows in a bulk operations, but from time to time between the working rows within a bulk update there are some rows not affected of the update. They are actually affected, because as I said, another auto-trigger filed receives a new value, that would mean that there is no problem with the transaction but the field I'm interested in is not changed.

Comment: possible locking issues with multiple concurrent activity?

Comment: If there was some locking problem, I would expect that will affect the entire row, but all the entries are changed. I'm thinking more in the direction how are the DATETIME fields being saved and if this addition of one second perhaps in some cases due to the conversion is not enough to increase it. Something like one second is not really a one second, if you know what I mean.